# grails 3 JSON converters marshallers

Tags: json, grails, marshalling

I'm using grails with simple domain (few fields and one link one to many to itself).

I've put a custom marshaller for JSON. All is working fine.

The problem that bother me is:
That Marshaller or getter setters are called hundred times per instance.

Example:

```
class Person{
     String name
     hasMany =[kids:Person]

  public String getName(){

       ....
      }

}
```

json code:

```
Person person = Person.findById(1)
person as JSON
```

Using **JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(JSONObject)** : tried in Bootstrap, in the domain and in service. The result is one and the same.

MArshaller or getters are invoked hundred times.
So for 1 person > 100 printed lines, 2 persons > 200.
The question is how can I trace what is doing this invokes and is it normal .

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do `JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(JSONObject)`. A JSONObject is already JSON.

Comment: You should use gson views instead. Much better performance. The converter API you are using is deprecated in Grails 3.3.0.M1

Comment: I'll search for the gson views . I'm using marshaller because I need to filter some fields and change others. If you have working example will be nice. Thank you.

Comment: http://views.grails.org/latest/

Comment: Thank you, James!